# Dropdown menu not hiding

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to have a `dropdown` menu toggle each time I click on a button. While the toggle works great and displays its content, I am facing problems with the reversed action and the menu hiding. I cannot find something working with what I have.

```
<div class="new-thread-container dropdown-toggle col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"
     aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown"></div>
```

I do not want to use `jQuery` but only `javascript`.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap then you just have to add bootstrap.js in you page and the dropdown will be working fine.

Comment: It does. It appears as hopped, but does not hide when I click outside the box... Or maybe it does but as I have a `div` with the parameter `rows="4"` and some buttons in it, those actually still display..?